# Undefined reference to QJson::Parser::Parser

Tags: c++, json, qt, undefined-reference, qjson

I've successfully(?) installed the QJson library following the instructions in the archive. But the compiler gives me this error:

```
Undefined reference to QJSon::Parser::Parser().
```

I've found where library files have been installed: it's `/usr/local/include/json` directory. But there are only `*.h` files in it.

The minimal code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <qjson/parser.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QJson::Parser parser;
    return a.exec();
}
```

I use linux.

Where are `*.cpp` files? What did I do wrong? Why isn't the library complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you have to find a library file rather than a `*.cpp` file. Maybe it
 has a name like `"libqjson.a"` or `"libqjson.so"` and compile this library with your code or pass this keys to

```
g++ -L(lib path) -lqjson
```

As it turned out (see comments below), your library path is `/usr/local/lib`, so this line becomes:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lqjson
```

Using Qt (qmake), just add this line to your `.pro` file in order to pass these two flags to g++:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lqjson
```

Comment: Also note that the `lib path` isn't the include path (`/usr/local/include/json`). Maybe the library files are installed in `/usr/local/lib/...`?

Comment: yes maybe, also maybe in /usr/lib or in any folder if you defind prefix during instalation

Comment: @zapredelom i didn't define any prefixes

Comment: @leemes there are libqjson.so, libqjson.so.0 and libqjson.0.7.1 files in /usr/local/lib dir.

Comment: so just pass "-L /usr/local/lib" and "-lqjson"  to gcc

Comment: Well... That's strange but I can't find compiler parameters in QtCreator. I've found build configuration, looked in Parameters->Build and Launch...

Comment: ... wihout the space after `-L`. Using Qt (qmake), just add this line to your `.pro` file in order to pass these two flags to g++: `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lqjson`

Comment: @zapredelom g++, not gcc, since these are C++ files.